# Diagnosing memory usage with google chrome: What are the values in the task manager columns?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I'm trying to figure out if my web app has memory issues such as leaks or if it uses too much but the tools that chrome gives are confusing. What are the different values that the task manager shows for each tab?

This is a heap snapshot of stackoverflow.com:

[image: Heap snapshot]

And these are the task manager values:

[image: Task manager]

The JS values in the task manager doesn't match with the memory heap snapshot and the Private  Memory is not the sum of any other values.

What does each value mean? Where do they come from?